# Using Maximum Principle to see conductor is equipotential

Tags: electrostatics

This is a problem from electrostatics, but I'm trying to understand it in terms of harmonic functions. Let $B\subset\mathbb{R^3}$ be a conductor. It can be shown that the electric potential $V:B\to\mathbb{R}$ is constant on $int(B)$ and $\nabla^2V=0$ on $int(B)$. Since $V$ is a harmonic function, it attains its max and min values on $\partial B$. Also, since $V$ is constant on $int(B)$, I feel this should imply that $V$ is actually constant over all $B$ and not just $int(B)$, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feeling is correct, since in this case $V$ is a continuous function as it is harmonic. So the constant value in $int(B)$ implies the same constant value for $\partial B$.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but don't we only know that $V$ is continuous on $int(B)$? If $V$ is continuous on all of $B$, then I agree. In that case though, I wonder if the maximum principle is even needed, given that we can show $V$ is constant on $int(B)$ without it.

Comment: For your question, I assumed you were talking about a conductor limited to a bounded region of the space $\mathbb{R^3}$ with some distribution of charge in its outside ($\mathbb{R^3} \backslash B$) and its boundary ($\partial B$). In such cases you have a continuous $V$ in all of $B$.

Comment: I think you have a continuous $V$ in any cases, since it is computed as the integral of ${\bf E}$ along a curve, for instance starting inside $Int(B)$. The function $V(x)= \int_{x_0}^{x} {\bf E}(z) \cdot d z$ is *always* continuous if it exists, even if ${\bf E}$ is discontinuous.

Comment: You can have a discontinuous $V$ in case you have a dipole-layer. Of course, this is an idealization, but in that case, you have a discontinuity $\Delta V = D/\epsilon_0$, where $D(x)$ is the dipole-layer distribution strength. See section 1.6 from Jackson to more details.